# Custom Button exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am newbie in WPF and C# development. I am trying create my own button class based on standard WPF button.

```
public class _BaseButton : Button
{
    public _BaseButton() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I try to place it in Window in XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <local:_BaseButton Height="30" Width="100" Content="I am crashing" VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="simpleButtonDetailCancelButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, in XAML code I define handler of PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event. It is implemented in window code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void simpleButtonDetailCancelButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The build of such a simple application finishes without errors. When I run  application, it crashes with following two exceptions:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to create a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown from the text simpleButtonDetailCancelButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown. Line number 7 and line position 10.
>
> ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Could you explain me what I am doing wrong? Something is wrong with definition of the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event handler, or it is missing in base class, but I do not know what I have to do to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The signature is incorrect. If I let visual studio define the signature it comes up with:

```
 private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

So your event args should be MouseButtonEventargs; not RoutedEventArgs

Comment: @Maroš Klempa: Why did you accept a copy of my original answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the second argument of the event handler to `MouseButtonEventArgs`:

```
private void simpleButtonDetailCancelButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
    MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{ 
}
```